# scala referencing value of a parameter

Tags: function, scala, types

If I have the following type and function:

```
object M {
    type X[Boolean] = Int => Boolean

    def retrieveVal(x: X[Boolean]) : Boolean = //retrieve the Boolean value of x
}
```

How would I go about retrieving and returning the boolean value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a peculiar type alias. It has a formal type parameter (the name of which is irrelevant and hence the choice of `Boolean` is misleading) that defines a function from `Int` to that arbitrary type. You then define a method, `retrieveVal` that takes a particular kind of `X` that happens to be `X[Boolean]` (here `Boolean` is an *actual* type parameter and hence *is* the `Boolean` we're familiar with) and returns some `Boolean`. However, the function `x` passed as an argument requires an `Int` argument and there is none in evidence.

So, if your `retrieveVal` were defined like this instead:

```
def retrieveVal(i: Int, x: X[Boolean]): Boolean = ...
```

you could define it like this:

```
def retrieveVal(i: Int, x: X[Boolean]): Boolean = x(i)
```

To wit:

```
scala> type X[Boolean] = Int => Boolean
defined type alias X

scala> def retrieveVal(i: Int, x: X[Boolean]): Boolean = x(i)
retrieveVal: (i: Int, x: Int => Boolean)Boolean

scala> retrieveVal(23, i => i % 2 == 0)
res0: Boolean = false
```

Comment: To explain the second sentence for someone unfamiliar with the terminology used: the definition of `X` is equivalent to `type X[T] = Int => T`, so you need to think if that's what you wanted or `type X = Int => Boolean` is instead.